# Norm inequality of Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $f\in L^1(R^d)$, where
$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int f(x) e^{-2\pi\xi i x}dx$$
and
$$\hat{f} = f$$
How may we prove
$$\|\hat{f}\|_p \leq \|f\|_1$$
holds?

I tried to use Holder's inequality, but end up in opposite direction, and the Hausdorff-Young was unable to deal with the gap between 1 and 2.

And insights are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have : $\| \hat{f} \|_{\infty} \le  \| f\|_1$
Thus,
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} | \hat{f}(t)|^p dt \le \| f\|_1^{p-1} \int_{\mathbb{R}} | \hat{f}(t)|dt= \| f\|_1^p$$
Done.